# want to shift button from top to buttom in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want to make a website like a medium, but I got stuck into a problem I am not able to shift the button from top to bottom whenever I hit the enter key. I am giving a screenshot
[image]

I do not understand how to implement the logic

this is my HTML code

```
<div class="content">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Article</legend>
    <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" style="background: transparent;border: 0px; width: 100%; margin-right: 5px;" appearance="none">
      <input matInput style="font-weight: bold; font-size:35px;" placeholder="Title">
    </mat-form-field>
    <hr>




       <div class="add">
          <div class="artical_section">
            <div class="add_remove">
              <button mat-icon-button (click)="addmore = !addmore" *ngIf="!addmore" class="add">
                <mat-icon class="icon"> add</mat-icon>
              </button>
              <button mat-icon-button class="remove" (click)="addmore = !addmore" *ngIf="addmore">
                <mat-icon class="icon">
                  clear
                </mat-icon>
              </button>
            </div>

            <div class="additional">
              <div class="button_list" *ngIf="addmore">

                <div class="buttons">
                  <button mat-icon-button class="button_style" (click)="addPhoto()">
                    <mat-icon class="icon">
                      camera_alt
                    </mat-icon>
                    <input type='file' #photoEvent (change)="onSelectPhoto($event)" multiple style="display:none">
                  </button>
                  <button mat-icon-button class="button_style" (click)="videoLink = !videoLink">
                    <mat-icon class="icon">
                      videocam
                    </mat-icon>
                  </button>
                  <button mat-icon-button class="button_style" (click)="twitterLink = !twitterLink">
                    <mat-icon class="icon">
                      code
                    </mat-icon>
                  </button>
                  <button mat-icon-button class="button_style">
                    <mat-icon class="icon">
                      emoji_emotions
                    </mat-icon>
                  </button>
                  <button mat-icon-button class="button_style">
                    <mat-icon class="icon">
                      gif
                    </mat-icon>
                  </button>




                </div>

              </div>
              <div #editor1 class="editor1" contenteditable="true">
                <img #image1 [src]="image" *ngIf="image!==null" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
                <input matInput placeholder="Paste Your Video Link" style="margin-top: 10px;" *ngIf="videoLink">
                <input matInput placeholder="Paste Your Link to embaded content to another site(e.g Twitter)" style="margin-top: 10px;" *ngIf="twitterLink">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
```

I want to use Only with javaScript or typeScript, not jquery.
Please help me out to solve, because I want to make a website like medium.com

thanks in advance

Comment: Where is contentEditable div?

Comment: @Kenny hey, In my sample code you'll find a div  in bottom where I have written class="editor1" that is contenteditable div

Comment: can you explain more about problem you have ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda hello, I you look into the medium.com website you'll find that, while writing an article when you hit the enter key from your keyboard the left side of plus button autocratically comes down i want this functionality how will I implement that. I hope you Understant

Comment: You can get height of right side of input tag and assign it to left side of  `+Button`, using angulars `ElementRef.nativeElement.offsetHeight` and assign it to `+Button` and makes both divs style align to bottom.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda thanks for your Idea can you  give demo, please

Comment: right hand side how you can manage input while entering?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8qdxp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html go to this link, here when you enter on input tag new formControl is created and then, only last `Plus(+) Button` displayed.

Comment: It will be easy to help you if you share a sample on jsfiddle.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda thanks I'll try

Comment: @GaurangDhorda can you give better solution then this, please

Comment: @PranjalDeb, Please create [mcve]. You can create a stack snippet here or add some jsfiddle/sandbox link